# Regarding Redirect Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I created a website in PHP, Now I am facing some issues please help me out.

```
https://www.example.com/ultrasound.php
```

above URL is working Fine

But when I add something after URL like

```
https://www.example.com/ultrasound.php/css
```

This shows a page where all my Html and CSS links and are showing, I need to stop these links

I need a clean URL using htaccess or any other method.

Comment: The feature that makes `/ultrasound.php/css` "work", is called _path info_, and you can deactivate it via the [`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive. If you do that, then this URL should simply result in a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a misunderstanding here. You don't actually need to mess around with htaccess or any other methods. It's crucial to grasp the basics of how URLs function.

Take a look at how you're referencing your URL:

```html
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is known as a relative path. The problem arises when this relative path gets appended to your current URL, which in this case is `/ultrasound.php`. Consequently, your browser will attempt to fetch the CSS from the URL `/ultrasound.php/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

If you're aiming to start from the root rather than relative to your page URL, the solution is straightforward – make sure to include the "/" at the beginning:

```html
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will ensure that your browser fetches the CSS from the correct absolute path, starting from the root. Understanding these basics will save you from unnecessary complications.

Comment: That is not really true. The browser will indeed create the requested path based on the current "locaton". But that creation will be based on the base directory of the currently loaded resource, so `/` in this example. Otherwise all relative links in the web would be broken which clearly is not the case. Relative references make much sense, since they keep solutions portable.

Comment: @arkascha Although it is true based on the example URL in the question (which I believe this answer is really getting at), ie. `/ultrasound.php/css` (although the use of `css` here is a bit misleading as it has nothing to do with the `css` in the relative URL. The same would apply to `/ultrasound.php/` and `/ultrasound.php/anything`.)

Comment: "this relative path gets appended to your current URL, which in this case is `/ultrasound.php`" - I know what you mean (although it's really appended to `/ultrasound.php/`), but this isn't strictly correct... _the relative path is resolved relative to the current URL, which in this case is `/ultrasound.php/css`_ (from the example in the question).

Comment: "You don't actually need to mess around with htaccess or any other methods." - Well, that depends whether you want URLs of the form `/ultrasound.php/anything` to be accessible (and looking at the site, probably not - which would seem to be what the OP is asking). By "fixing" the relative URL to be root-relative you know have a potential duplicate content issue (particularly since there doesn't appear to be a `rel="canonical"` tag on the page).

Comment: @MrWhite That would mean that the current URL is `/ultrasound.php/`, not `/ultrasound.php` which is _not_ what is stated in the question. Obviously, in that situation the relative reference would get appended to that base URL. But that is a different question. What is writte here in this answer is not working as explained.

Comment: @arkascha The problematic URL stated in the question is `/ultrasound.php/css`.

Comment: @MrWhite It is, but that can _not_ be a result of `/ultrasound.php` being loaded which contains a relative reference to `css/...`. So those are two separate things. Either what is said in the question is wrong, or two separate cases are mixed in the question without saying so. Whatever is the case - what is claimed _here_ in the answer is clearly wrong. Here it is claimed that when `/ultrasound.php` is loaded that the browser will interpret `css/...` by appenting it to `/ultrasound.php/css/...`. That is _wrong_ .

Comment: I responded too quickly because I had visited the URL mentioned in the original question - https://www.drpreetirastogi.com/ultrasound.php - and I observed that the `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` code was causing the download of `ultrasound.php/css/bootstrap.min.css`, and I didn't give it a second thought.

While my answer may technically address the problem I observed, it is incorrect in terms of understanding the underlying cause.